# Inserting Day into Array If Doesn't Exist - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following array, which contains an array of weeks. Within each week is an array of days:

```
  weeks: Array(4)
    0: Array(4)
      days: Array(4)
        0: {name: "Tuesday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-22T01:00:00.000Z"}
        1: {name: "Wednesday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-23T01:00:00.000Z"}
        2: {name: "Thursday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-24T01:00:00.000Z"}
        3: {name: "Friday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-25T01:00:00.000Z"}
    1: Array(4)
      days: Array(4)
        0: {name: "Monday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-22T01:00:00.000Z"}
        1: {name: "Tuesday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-23T01:00:00.000Z"}
        2: {name: "Wednesday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-24T01:00:00.000Z"}
        3: {name: "Thursday", sessions: Array(2), date: "2020-09-25T01:00:00.000Z"}
```

However, some weeks like the ones above are missing days, the first one is missing Monday and the second one is missing Friday. How can I loop through the weeks array, checking for missing days, and adding them in if they are missing, along with the correct date for that day?

Also, within each day, is a sessions array, which contains the following data:

```
sessions: Array(2)
  0:
    code: "N/A"
    session: "AM"
  0:
    code: "N/A"
    session: "PM"
```

How would I add this sessions array (with these exact values) into each day that I am adding?

This is what I have so far:

```
for (const week of weeks) 
  {
    let monday = false;

    for (const day of week) 
     {
       if (day.name === 'Monday') 
         {
           monday = true;
         }      
      }
    if (monday === false)
      {
        //ADD DAY HERE
      }
  }
```

Thanks in Advance For Any Help

Comment: Use null coalescing

Answer (score 0):

first, you should loop over each week.
for each week you should make an array of booleans the size of 7(or however many days you want there to be)
go over every day of the week, check the name and set the appropriate location in the array to true (if the name is sunday, set the first element to true etc...)
after that, you should check which days are missing using the boolean array.

you should add all the missing days, first, get the name according to the location in the boolean array, to generate the date string you have to use a Date object, you need some way of knowing at what time the week starts, this part you probably know how to do.

to make the sessions array you could just declare it with something along the lines of:

```
day.sessions=[{code:"N/A",session:"AM"},{code:"N/A",session:"PM"}];
```

Edit: to add a new day to the array, you could do

```
week.push(day)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @GideonMax, I have updated my question, could you possibly give me an example for the //ADD DAY HERE line? I'm just not sure how to add a day to the days array, and get the correct date, thanks

Comment: Thanks you @GideonMax, that works, the only thing I need to do now is add in the correct date for the day, do you know how I could work that out?

Comment: @SuperPiglet do you have a way of knowing when the week starts?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: do you have a way of knowing which week the week is and in which year?

Comment: no, I will only be able to work it out based on the days already listed for that week.

Comment: well, you could pick one of the days that is already in said week, take its date and then subtract from that date multiple days according to which day you picked, for example, if you pick monday, you should subtract 1 day to get to sunday, which is the first day of the week.

Comment: Thanks @GideonMax, how do I subtract or add one day from a date variable?

Comment: you can get the amount of milliseconds from the Date, this is the amount of milliseconds that have passed since 1/1/1970 00:00. then you can subtract from that 1000*60*60*24 to subtract a single day, than you can construct another Date object using that number

Answer (score 0):

As long as we're just filling in the blanks, it's pretty straight forward.

1. Setup a day `enum`(`days`) to ensure array order is accurate
2. Loop through the data
3. Get a `reference` to a date available in the existing `week array` (we'll use this later)
4. Reduce the existing `week array` into a `week object` where the key is the `day` name and value is the existing `week data`
5. Take our existing `enum` get only the `numerical` values, sort by the `numerical` values and then perform the below operation

   1. Get the corresponding `day` for the `numerical` value
   2. Check if the `day` exists in our `week object`
   3. If it does, return the existing `week object`
   4. else, create a `week object`
6. Creating a `week object`

   1. We already have the corresponding `day`, use that as the `name`
   2. The `sessions` we can just create
   3. `date` is the tricky part
7. Establishing the `date`

   1. Check if the current `day` index is greater than or less than our `reference index`
   2. If less than, we want to create a new `date` using our `reference date`, and then shift that created date by the difference between our current `day` index and our `reference index`. e.g.

   ```
   // Tuesday < Thursday
   1 < 3 // true
   3 - 1 // 2
   // We know that we need to shift our reference date(Thursday) 2 days back to get Tuesday's date
   ```

   3. if greater than, apply the same strategy in reverse

```js
// Input Data
const weeks = [
  [{
      name: "Tuesday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-22T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Wednesday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-23T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Thursday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-24T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Friday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-25T01:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "Monday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-22T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Tuesday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-23T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Wednesday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-24T01:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      name: "Thursday",
      sessions: [{
          code: "N/A",
          session: "AM"
        },
        {
          code: "N/A",
          session: "PM"
        }
      ],
      date: "2020-09-25T01:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
];

//  Actual Code

const days = {
  0: "Monday",
  1: "Tuesday",
  2: "Wednesday",
  3: "Thursday",
  4: "Friday",
  Monday: 0,
  Tuesday: 1,
  Wednesday: 2,
  Thursday: 3,
  Friday: 4
};

function handleWeek(week) {
  const referenceDate = new Date(week[0].date),
    referenceIndex = days[week[0].name];
  const weekObject = week.reduce((acc, cv) => (Object.assign(Object.assign({}, acc), {
    [cv.name]: cv
  })), {});
  return Object.keys(days)
    .filter(key => !isNaN(+key))
    .sort()
    .map((dayIndex, index) => {
      const day = days[dayIndex];
      return weekObject[day] ?
        weekObject[day] : {
          name: day,
          sessions: [{
              code: "N/A",
              session: "AM"
            },
            {
              code: "N/A",
              session: "PM"
            }
          ],
          date: referenceIndex < index ?
            new Date(new Date(referenceDate).setDate(referenceDate.getDate() + (index - referenceIndex))).toISOString() : new Date(new Date(referenceDate).setDate(referenceDate.getDate() - (referenceIndex - index))).toISOString()
        };
    });
}
const result = weeks.map(week => handleWeek(week));
console.log(result);
```